# Calculus Minimum question (Cone in a cylinder)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

About a given cylinder of radius r circumscribe a right cone of minimum volume; we assume the planes and centers of the circular bases of the cylinder and the cone coincide. Find the radius of the base of the cone.

Comment: By your question, the answer should remain r. You havent really explained the constraints clearly.

Comment: the problem is that this is all the information the book gives. It says the answer is (3/2)r.